# Numerical coding and constraints for categorical variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data

I know that using numerical coding is wrong but I'm trying to understand exactly *why*.
Suppose we want to fit the model $\text{prestige} = \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}\text{education}+\beta_{2}\text{type}+\epsilon$ and $\epsilon \sim N(\textbf{0},\sigma^{2}I_{n})$ where 'type' means occupation type.

If we were to encode for the categorical variable $\text{type}$ with three categories, blue collar, professional and white collar with 1, 2, and 3 respectively, we get 'unwanted assumptions/constraints' on the location of the intercepts.

Can someone please explain what is meant by this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that encoding $type$ with the numbers $\{1,2,3 \}$ leads to three major problems:

1) Giving a clear ranking between *blue collar*, *professional* and *white collar* automatically gives some pre-assumptions about the dependence structure in your model. Because if we have for example a $\beta_2>0$, then you assume that the effect of prestige for *white collar* must be stronger than for *professional* or *white collar*.

2) And more importantly it leads to the assumption that the difference between the three categories is equally spaced. I.e. you implicitly assume that the difference between *blue collar* and *professional* is the same as the difference between *professional* and *white collar*, while the difference between *blue collar* and *white collar* is twice the difference of them.

3) Somewhat related, but noteworthy, is that you also assume that $type$ is a real valued continuous variable what in fact is not true.

Hence, the best solution would be to introduce three dummy variables $bc=I(blue collar=T)$, $pr=I(professional=T)$ and $wc=I(white collar=T)$, that are one if the statement in the indicator function $I(\cdot)$ is true.

Then you leave out the constant and form a model like:

$$prestige=bc + pr + wc+\beta_1education+\epsilon,\epsilon∼N(0,\sigma^2I) $$

With this dummy specification you circumvent the problems 1)-3) as you do not need to assume a ranking, you also impose no spacing of the difference between the categories and additionally you code it binary instead of real valued.