# Dummy Variables vs Categorical Variables

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I'm trying to analyze political effects in US Presidential elections.

Red States= Republican wins by >=5%
Blue States = Democrat wins by >=5%
Battleground States = In-Between

Hypotheses:
H1 Null Ho Red vs Battleground is more Signif than Blue vs Battleground in affecting Y
H1 Alternate HA Blue vs Battleground is more Signif than Red vs Battleground in affecting Y

H2 Null Ho Political Extremism in State (ie EITHER Red or Blue) is more Signif than Battleground in affecting Y
H2 Alternate HA Battleground is more Signif than Political Extremism in State (ie EITHER Red or Blue) in affecting Y

How would I set up dummy or categorical explanatory variables for this type of model? It seems perplexing.

I've thought of 2 possible solutions, but they both seem wrong:

a) I have a dummy variable RED (=1 if state is Red State; =0 if Blue or Battleground),
I have a dummy variable BATTLE (=1 if state is Battleground; =0 if not Battleground).

b) I have a categorical variable RED (=1 if state is Red State; =0 if Battleground; =-1 if Blue State),
I have a dummy variable BATTLE (=1 if state is Battleground; =0 if not Battleground).

What if I instead have variables like these:

c) I have a dummy variable RED (=1 if state is Red State; =0 if Blue or Battleground),
I have a dummy variable REDBLUE (=1 if state is Red or Blue; =0 if IS Battleground).

Then the following combinations of RED,REDBLUE mean the following:
1,1 Red State
0,1 Blue State
0,0 Battleground

Comparing the significances of the RED coefficient (vs 0) helps us resolve Hypothesis H1; and of the REDBLUE coefficient, Hypothesis H2. Am I making the correct conclusion here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do, but the traditional way of encoding a categorical variable with 3 levels ('red', 'blue', 'battle') is to create 2 dummy variables. The first dummy, red, takes on value 1 if the state is red and 0 otherwise. The second dummy, blue, takes on value 1 if the state is blue and 0 otherwise. That's all you need - note that if the state is red then _only_ the "red dummy" will be 1; if the state is blue then _only_ the "blue dummy" will be equal to 1; and if the state is battleground then neither the "red dummy" and the "blue dummy" will be 0

Comment: Note that this encoding would imply that "battleground" is your reference (or baseline) category. This means that the coefficients for "red" and "blue" should be interpreted as the difference between red states and battleground states, and as the difference between blue states and battleground states, respectively. If you wanted a different level to be the reference, you'd just need to leave that level out instead when creating the two dummy variables for the other levels.

Comment: @AdriàLuz Your solution sounds great for testing Hypothesis H1 but in Hypothesis H2 I have to test Battleground States vs (Either Red or Blue States ie Political Extremism). How would I do that 2nd part?

Comment: @AdriàLuz I've read in several places online about the problem of constrained effects with categorical variables too--the implicit assumption of equal spacing and equal magnitude being implied: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278837/numerical-coding-and-constraints-for-categorical-variables
I was to avoid all that too :)

Comment: Re: your first comment: to test H2 you will need to use bespoke contrasts with ANOVA ([this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/doing-and-reporting-your-first-planned-contrasts-in-r-ee77ff277088) might be helpful). Re: your second comment: that would only be a problem if you coded up your categorical variable as a 1, 2, 3 for red, blue, and battleground states respectively. I haven't suggested you do that. Coding it up in the way I suggested (with dummy variables) won't give you any problems.

Comment: You've already applied a transformation that results in loss of information: states that vote 5% in favor of one party are as "extreme" as states that vote 7%, states that vote 10%, etc. This binning of a continuous variable (for political preferences) is much more important than the encoding mentioned in the question.

Comment: @dipetkov A problem with continuous variables is that the difference between +3% and -3% looks the same as +9% and +3%, even though in the first case the states are likely both battleground states, but in the second case it is much more likely that both states have the same political party preference. Another problem is testing the hypothesis of (Battleground) vs (Either Red or Blue)

Comment: @AdriàLuz I've never used ANOVA before. Just read about it in school many years ago. Same with R. I'll try to figure it out in Stata or SAS. Thanks very much.

Comment: About the difference between +3% and -3% vs the difference between +9% and +3%: relationships between variables don't have to be linear, though it's often a default modeling choice. Anyway, I just wanted to point out that applying thresholds may seem like solving a problem but underneath results in loss of information. And unless +5%/-5% is a threshold agreed upon by all, explaining the choice of threshold can be its own issue.

Comment: @dipetkov The 5% threshold appears to be a standard among political analysts every time an election is discussed. I don't have a political background but that is my understanding. I do get what you mean though about information being lost. And your point about linearity is also well taken. A state that's at 12% is not necessarily twice as extreme as a state at 6%.